# Get the first two words separated by comma and space and swap the order

Tags: excel, substitution

I have a string (in H2):

```
LARSON, JOHN (PIZZA MAKERS INC)
```

...and I only want the name to result in:

```
JOHN LARSON
```

So far I have the following (in I2) to get the name only but need to swap the order.

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(H2,FIND(" ",H2,FIND(" ",H2)+1)-1),",","")
```

and have a second column (J2) with the following to swap but there must be a cleaner method.

```
 =MID(I2&" "&I2,FIND(" ",I2)+1,LEN(I2))
```

Any clues or hints? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, but it does the job as long as the format is always `<LASTNAME>, <FIRSTNAME> <WHATEVER>`:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(",",A1, 1)+2, FIND(" ", A1, FIND(",", A1, 1)+2) - FIND(",", A1, 1) - 2) & " " & LEFT(A1,FIND(",", A1, 1)-1)
```

It may be cleaner to solve this in VBA with a UDF:

```
Function getName(bigNameString As String) As String
    Dim lastName As String, firstName As String
    lastName = Left(Split(bigNameString, " ")(0), Len(Split(bigNameString, " ")(0)) - 1)
    firstName = Split(bigNameString, " ")(1)
    getName = firstName & " " & lastName
End Function
```

Just stick that in a new module, save the workbook (with .xlsm suffix) and you can use that in a cell:

```
=getName(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND(",", A2)+1, TEXT(,)), " ", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2))&LEFT(A2, FIND(",", A2)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF that uses Regular Expressions to extract (and reverse) the first two comma-separated substrings from a string.

```
Option Explicit
Function getName(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\w+),\s*(\w+).*"
    getName = .Replace(S, "$2 $1")
End With

End Function
```

And here is the explanation of the Regex and replacement string

### to Extract the Names

```
(\w+),\s*(\w+).*
```

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\w+)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “word character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the character “,” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `,`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\w+)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “word character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

$2 $1

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`
- [Insert the character “ ” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)